# Rewrite URL with .htaccess to hide PHP extension

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I've a question, I'm developing a webservice for a specific app.
Last week I transferred my back-up from server1 to server2, since that moment my .htaccess won't work anymore.

The url for my webservice is:
http://apps.holtesdesign.nl/inholland/apiv0/

This url works fine, to load the bugreport module:
http://apps.holtesdesign.nl/inholland/apiv0/bugreport.php

But the url was supposed to be:
http://apps.holtesdesign.nl/inholland/apiv0/bugreport

When you'll open the last url, you'll see that it will result in an internal server error.
Do you know how it's possible?

My .htaccess looks like:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

The server is running on CentOS, and I've already checked if mod_rewrite is functioning...

I hope you can help me guys!

Cheers,

Jelmer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will fix it:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1\.php
```

---

If it doesn't work correct the settings of your Wamp Server:

1. Left click WAMP icon
2. Apache
3. Apache Modules
4. Left click rewrite_module.

Comment: unfortunately, it won't. I've replaced the .htacces file with your code

Comment: Where is the .htaccess file?

Comment: The .htaccess file was in the same directory, now I've deleted it, and put it in the parent directory, which worked with your code. 

It was a very strange problem!

Answer (score 4):

This will hide the trailing slash and hide .php in root & sub directories.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

try this.. it works! :)

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Working Concept for me:

```
# Options is required by Many HostSevice
Options +MultiViews

RewriteEngine on

# For .php & .html URL's:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

Use this code in Root folder of your website in .htaccess File : Example

offline - wamp\www\YourWebDir

online - public_html/

> Important Note : If it doesn't work correct the settings of your Wamp
>   Server: 1) Left click WAMP icon 2) Apache 3) Apache Modules 4) Left
>   click rewrite_module