# url rewriting issue need to hide .php extension

Tags: url-rewriting

I want URL rewriting solution.
I have this URL [http://dailyimage.in/photo.php/1480]
and I want to hide .php or [http://dailyimage.in/photo/1480] this type URL

Now I am using this code but it's not working in my **.htaccess file**

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rewrite URL with .htaccess to hide PHP extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18177290/rewrite-url-with-htaccess-to-hide-php-extension)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try instead of using `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php` using `%{REQUEST_URI}.php` in your rewrite destination :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [QSA,L]
```